# Why isn't this variable raising when a function is executed?

Tags: javascript, variables

So I'm making an idle game and I want when you buy a 'carrot patch' in this example, the price of said 'carrot patch' will raise by 50%. However this doesn't happen.

Here's my code:

```
var patchPrice = 10;

function buyPatch() {
   if (affordable = true) {
      var patchPrice = patchPrice * 1.5;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have declared the patchPrice variable twice. so it will overwrite the previous value. just remove the second var and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

These were problems with js before es6 I recommend you to use es6 const and let to declare variables.

Answer (score -1):

Try == in the comparison or simply omit the (== true) as it is already a boolean.

```
var patchPrice = 10;
function buyPatch() {
   if (affordable == true) {
      var patchPrice = patchPrice * 1.5;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using "VAR" unless you wanna work with function scope variables.